# Printing output by inside method

Tags: c#, methods

Simply want to ask from below code that how can we print **max value** from writing inside the **FindMax Method** instead of executing print from **main method** after calling **Find Max** method ?

```
using System;

namespace CalculatorApplication

{
   class NumberManipulator
   {
      public int FindMax(int num1, int.  num2)
      {
         /* local variable declaration */
        int result;

        if (num1 > num2)
        result = num1;
        else
        result  return result;
      }
        static void Main(string[] args)
      {
        /* local variable definition */
        int a = 100;
        int b = 200;
        int ret;
        NumberManipulator n = new. NumberManipulator();

        //calling the FindMax method
        ret = n.FindMax(a, b);
        Console.WriteLine("Max value is :    {0}", ret );
        Console.ReadLine();
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Why did you tag this Java?

Comment: Also did you even try just putting a `Console.WriteLine` inside the method?

Comment: Why not moving the line
   Console.WriteLine("Max value is :    {0}", result);
to FindMax method?

Comment: @UnholySheep Tagging java might get answer fast and even if i tried putting inside method how to match parameters with a,b and num1,num2 i cant simply it

Comment: No, tagging an unrelated language will not make you get answers faster - it will get you downvotes faster. Also what parameters are you matching? Your print does nothing of the sort (and it sounds like you need a good beginners tutorial, not SO)

Comment: @UnholySheep yes that's why i m posting it here to improve and I am learning c#  alone from TP so beginners always make that kind of mistakes if u dont mind.

Comment: The code has tons of small errors like: `(int num1, int.  num2)`, just copy and paste the full code that runs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your main function you are printing what the function returns, after you call it:

```
ret = n.FindMax(a, b); //calls function with params a and b
        Console.WriteLine("Max value is :    {0}", ret ); //prints out the value returned by FindMax
```

So, to make your function print out the result, just print out the result inside the function, instead of returning it. Replace the `return result;` in `FindMax` with `Console.WriteLine("Max value is :    {0}", result );`, since you want to print `result` instead of returning it.

Now in your `Main` function instead of setting `ret` to the return of `FindMax`, and printing it out, just call `n.FindMax(a, b);`, and it will print the result.

Also, you have to change `public int FindMax(int num1, int num2)` to `public void FindMax(int num1, int.  num2)`, since it doesn't return anything ([see the doc page for more info on void](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/csharp/language-reference/keywords/void)).

*I highly recommend that you just leave it how it is, but this is how you do it. (I'm not sure if you still want to return the value, I interpreted that you just want to print it out when the function is called*

Comment: Thanks I was waiting for reply ,such a big mistake.

Comment: Yes.. why not, it will help